# Is There any exec() function in c as in python

Tags: python, c

**This is the Python Code to Execute external python files**

```
exec(open("file.py").read())
```

**How to do it in c**

Comment: Just to mention that this is hardly the best way to execute other python files in python.

Comment: How do you imagine this to work in details? Since C is a compiled language should it run a compiled artefact, compiled the code or interpret the source?

Comment: "This is the Python Code to Execute external python files" this is generally not what one would do in Python. What are you actually tryin to accomplish?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <list>

class PrivateDriverData {
    public:
        std::string PythonExecutable = "python3";
        std::string exec(std::string command) {
            char buffer[128];
            std::string result = "";
            // Open pipe to file
            FILE* pipe = popen(command.c_str(), "r");
            if (!pipe) {
                return "popen failed!";
            }
            while (!feof(pipe)) {
                if (fgets(buffer, 128, pipe) != NULL)
                    result += buffer;
            }
            pclose(pipe);
            return result;
        }
};

std::string ExecDriver() {

    PrivateDriverData LocalPDD;
    
    std::string ScraperExecuteData = LocalPDD.PythonExecutable + " file.py";

    return LocalPDD.exec(ScraperExecuteData);
}

int main() {
    std::string answer = ExecDriver();
    std::cout << answer << "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The closet thing C has is dlopen().  which open a compiled and linked dynamic library and provides a way to run the code it contains.

It's not standard C and requires a hosted environment so it's not going to work on Arduino etc.